# Create context menu in Scene view

Tags: unity, c#, gui, menu

I created some `MenuItem`functions for navigating, which are currently displayed on the menu toolbar. The C# code:

```
using UnityEditor;
using UnityEngine;

public class Menu : MonoBehaviour {

static void rotateView(Quaternion rotation) {
    SceneView.lastActiveSceneView.LookAt(SceneView.lastActiveSceneView.pivot, rotation);

    SceneView.lastActiveSceneView.Repaint();
}

[MenuItem("View/Front _1")] // FRONT
static void FrontView() {
    rotateView(Quaternion.Euler(0, 180, 0));
}

[MenuItem("View/Back &1")] // BACK
static void BackView() {
    rotateView(Quaternion.Euler(0, 0, 0));
}

// Few more similar functions

}
```

I came from Blender, where there are shortcuts opening a context menu on the cursor position like this one, opened after pressing `U`:

[image: Blender context menu]

What I want to do is displaying a context menu after pressing `P` which would display a list of implemented `MenuItems`.
Is something like this possible in Unity?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ScreenToWorldPoint` to convert your mouse positions to 3D coordinates.

Also `ScreenToViewportPoint` converts your mouse positions to normalized 2D coordinates on current viewport.

Usage:

`ReferenceCamera.ScreenToWorldPoint(mouseX,mouseY,distanceFromCamera)`

Where

`mouseX = ReferenceCamera.ScreenToViewportPoint(Input.mousePosition).x`

`mouseY = ReferenceCamera.ScreenToViewportPoint(Input.mousePosition).y`

- `ScreenToViewportPoint` gives you a value between 0 and 1 normalized for the screen you are playing in. Very useful for placement of UI elements on HUD. This is probably what you are looking for.
- `ScreenToWorldPoint` is used to get world position. This is useful if you want to create an explosion at x distance from screen for a game with orthographic projection.

Create a HUD. Attach it to camera. Check `ScreenToViewportPoint` and calculate if the menu should spawn to bottom-right/bottom-left/top-left/top-right so it doesnt go out of bounds. You can track selections through same method.

Comment: This answer would be more useful if it elaborated on the steps of "Create a HUD" and how one would attach a HUD to the scene view camera, not the MainCamera object that renders the game.